# Outlook 2007 contact indexing issue

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook

I have a user whom is running Outlook 2007 on XP and has a large amount of contacts (I would say around 300-500 contacts) and when he creates a new contact it does not get indexed.

In other words it is created but you can’t do a search, you have to manually find it in the list of names.

My original guess was that this is caused by the volume of the items but I would like to find a solution for this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: No it's not caused by the volume of contacts. I had at one point over a thousand contacts in Outlook and it was searchable. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Might be some corruption in the data file. Here is a link to an Office Support article which might be helpful - [Repair Outlook Data Files (.pst and .ost)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-HA010075831.aspx).

Running these tools will ensure the data files are in good shape and could very possibly resolve the contact issue. If not, at least you will know the integrity of the files as you continue to troubleshoot.